# Encrypting many buffers with same key

Tags: security, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I have a large dataset (say 1GB) comprised of many blocks, some with a size of ~ 100 bytes, some around a megabyte.  Each block is encrypted by AES-GCM, with the **same** 128b key (and different IV, naturally). I have a structure that keeps the offset and length of each encrypted block, with its IV and GCM tag.

*Question*: if I encrypt the structure (thus hiding the beginning, length and IV/tag of each encrypted block), will it make my data safer? Or its ok to leave all thousand(s) encrypted blocks in the open, for anybody to see where each starts and ends, and what is its IV/tag? The block size is fairly standard, and doesn't reveal much about the data. My concern is with direct attacks on the key and data (with thousands of encrypted samples available) - or other indirect attacks.

Comment: What is the purpose of your data set? As in could the block sizes give clues to what your data is? As an example in video encryption, videos use more bytes when motion is happening (possibly at the changing of a security guard), so it depends what kind of information you're trying to keep secret.

Comment: Good point. The block sizes are fairly standard, and don't reveal much about the data. I'll add this to the question text.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the comments you've answered most of your own question. If the question is "do I need to encrypt the structure?" then the next question (as YAHsaves notes) is "is the structure itself sensitive information?" If the answer is no, then that's your answer. To the extent that the structure itself is sensitive, it should be protected.

If there are attacks on your key due to repeated use with unique IVs, then this indicates incorrect use of GCM, and should be resolved. GCM is designed to support key reuse if used correctly. NIST provides good and explicit guidance on how to design GCM systems in [NIST 800-38d](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf). In particular, you want to read section 8, and especially 8.2.1 on the the recommended construction of IVs (and 8.3 if you do not use the recommended IV construction).

Most of NIST's guidance can be summed up as "make sure that Key+IV is never reused, ever, and if you can't 100% guarantee it, then guarantee it to at least 2^-31 (99.9999999%), no seriously, we aren't kidding, don't reuse Key+IV, not even once."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found an additional answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789665/9390627). It addresses a different question, but applied to mine, it means: Yes, its ok to leave in the open view  thousands of blocks, encrypted with the same key. Actually, up to a ~ billion should be OK - in both random and deterministic IV modes of AES-GCM.